# Get the EditText values from ListView, make the double and do calculations

Tags: java, android, listview

I have stuck with my code..

I have create an ArrayList with EditTexts, where the user fill and I am trying to get the values from those (which are doubles), make some calculations and show them to another ArrayList with TextViews.

This is the first time I am using this code...

```
counter++;

EditText ed;
List<EditText> allEds = new ArrayList<EditText>();
TextView tv;
List<TextView> allTvs = new ArrayList<TextView>();

ed = new EditText(Main_5.this);
allEds.add(ed);
ed.setId(counter);
ed.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.5f));
linearLayout.addView(ed);
ed.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER| InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);

tv = new TextView(Main_5.this);
allTvs.add(tv);
tv.setId(counter);
tv.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.5f));
linearLayout.addView(tv);
```

Until this part is working and creates the EditText and TextViews on the button's click.

For the retrieve and make the string to double, I have think this, but it doesn't work :(

```
Double[] doubles = new Double[allEds.size()];
String[] strings = new String[allEds.size()];

for(i=0;i<allEds.size();i++){

   strings[i] = allEds.get(i).getText().toString();
   doubles[i] = Double.parseDouble(strings[i]);
}
```

Can anyone help me?? Thank you!!

**UPDATE**
After the changes, I am posting my code, if anyone can find out the problem..
 
My xml file is:

```
   < RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"<br/>
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" <br/>android:layout_width="match_parent"<br/>
    android:layout_height="match_parent" <br/>android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"<br/>
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"<br/>
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"<br/>
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" <br/>tools:context=".MainActivity"><br/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/txtInput"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/txtInput2"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/txtInput3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/delete"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/txtInput3"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtInput3"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/delete"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/delete"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtInput3">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
 </ScrollView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/add"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:text=""
    android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
    android:tint="#91d1be"
    android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="11dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtInput"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtInput3"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/txtInput3"
     />
```

And my java file is:

```
public class Main_5 extends Activity {

private LinearLayout mainLinearLayout;
int counter=0, i=0;

EditText mEditText1,mEditText2,mEditText3;
TextView mTextView;
Button add,delete;
Double calculatedValue;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_5);

    mEditText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtInput);
    mEditText2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtInput2);
    mEditText3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtInput3);
    mTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
    mainLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if ((String.valueOf(mEditText1.getText()).length() == 0) ||
                    (String.valueOf(mEditText2.getText()).length() == 0) ||
                    (String.valueOf(mEditText3.getText()).length() == 0))
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fill the fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            else {
                Double value1 = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(mEditText1.getText()));
                Double value2 = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(mEditText2.getText()));
                Double value3 = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(mEditText3.getText()));

                calculatedValue = (value2 / value3);
                mTextView.setText(calculatedValue.toString());

                counter++;

                LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(Main_5.this);
                TableLayout.LayoutParams lp = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);
                linearLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
                linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

                EditText ed;
                List<EditText> allEds = new ArrayList<EditText>();
                TextView tv;
                List<TextView> allTvs = new ArrayList<TextView>();

                ed = new EditText(Main_5.this);
                allEds.add(ed);
                ed.setId(counter);
                ed.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.5f));
                linearLayout.addView(ed);
                ed.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER| InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);

                tv = new TextView(Main_5.this);
                allTvs.add(tv);
                tv.setId(counter);
                tv.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.5f));
                linearLayout.addView(tv);

                mainLinearLayout.addView(linearLayout);

                Double[] doubles = new Double[allEds.size()];
                String[] strings = new String[allEds.size()];
                Double[] results = new Double[allEds.size()];
                String[] resultStrings = new String[allTvs.size()];

                for(i=0;i<allEds.size();i++){

                    strings[i] = allEds.get(i).getText().toString();
                    if(strings[i].length()>0){
                        doubles[i] = Double.parseDouble(strings[i]);

                        results[i] = (doubles[i]*value2);

                        resultStrings[i] = Double.toString(results[i]);

                       allTvs.get(i).setText(String.valueOf(results[i]));

                    }}}}});}}
```

(I closed all at once for less space ;P )
Is anyone who can help?? My problem is that I can't see the results on TextViews...
Thank you!!

Comment: What is the exact problem you're having? What isn't working?

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: I don't have problem with the first code, I just post it to see what I have done... 
I have problem with the second code, where I am trying to retrieve the data and use them.. I don't know if it is correct or not.. 
the error that I have it says that it is: <br/>java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "" <br/> at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63) <br/> at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:248)<br/><br/>

Can anyone help me to use the data I am getting from the user?? Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I got your problem. You're trying to convert empty strings to double values. That's why you're getting NumberFormatException. Your code should be like this:

```
Double[] doubles = new Double[allEds.size()];
String[] strings = new String[allEds.size()];

for(i=0;i<allEds.size();i++){

   strings[i] = allEds.get(i).getText().toString();
   if(strings[i].length()>0){
       doubles[i] = Double.parseDouble(strings[i]);
   }
}
```

Comment: That's great!! It works.. But how I am going to saw ex. doubles[1] to tv[1], doubles[2] to tv[2] etc.??

Comment: For that, try the following code `tv[1].setText(String.valueOf(doubles[1]));`

Comment: I believe you're using List of TextViews, so for that, try the following updated code `allTvs.get(1).setText(String.valueOf(doubles[1]));`

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work...
I make some calculations and I put the results on a double array with the name     Double[] results = new Double[allEds.size()];   then, inside the for, I tried to put the results into the TextView I make from the List, with the code    allTvs.get(i).setText(String.valueOf(results [i]));   but I didn't see anything on the app..

Comment: Is anyone who could help me?? I am trying but I can't figure this out...

Comment: I believe there are logical errors in your code, that's why you're not able to see the expected results. If there would have been any exceptions, the app might have crashed.

Comment: You've provided partial code of your application,that's why I won't be able to help you more on that.

Comment: I am going to update the code in my post if you could try to find any solutions... Thank you!!

Comment: Can you zip the entire code and provide a Dropbox-like link so that we can try it on our own machines?

Comment: I made some tries to find the root of the problem and I saw that it didn't get the data from allEds.. I set to show on allTvs, in every position, the value1 and it works!! Then, I set to show the strings[i] and it didn't work... so, I realized that it doesn't take the data from the list, or it saves them wrong... I upload the code here https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B64fO-0X1FzOYUJiQnVaTmZaZUU ,if anyone would like to give a try it would be very nice, because I am really stuck... I am sure is something stupid that I miss... Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

It is due to `java.lang.NumberFormatException`, which means either you are converting an empty or non-numerical string into `Double`. 
Filter the string before conversion in the loop as,

```
Double[] doubles = new Double[allEds.size()];
String[] strings = new String[allEds.size()];

for(i=0;i<allEds.size();i++){

strings[i] = allEds.get(i).getText().toString();

//Say no to NumberFormatException
if(strings[i] == null) {
     doubles[i] = 0.0; 
  } else if(strings[i].trim().length < 1){
     doubles[i] = 0.0; 
 } else {
    doubles[i] = Double.parseDouble(strings[i]);
 }

 //now set the textview text
 allTvs.get(i).setText(doubles[i] + ""); //Yeah,  + ""

/* If the textView text didn't change for some reasons (which I don't know)
   then get the textView  and set its text then replace it with the one in 
   list
   e.g:/ 
 */

 TextView tv = allTvs.get(i);
 tv.setText(doubles[i] + "");
 allTvs.add(i, tv);
}
```